# Are questions about online resources on-topic?

Tags: discussion, appropriate-questions, questions

Sometimes, questions about English (online) resources are being asked. Are those questions on-topic for EL&U? If they are on-topic, aren't they at least subjective?

These are examples of questions about resources; some of the questions have been closed, and some not. That is the reason I am asking this question.

- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9963/resources-for-english-business-language
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/advice-resources-for-indian-english-speakers
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5646/descriptive-writing-cambridge-english-language-tips-and-resources
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2921/good-resources-to-learn-how-to-write-mails
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18566/resources-to-teach-english
- [Are there resources or tools for "reverse etymology"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19864/are-there-resources-or-tools-for-reverse-etymology)
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7211/list-of-good-resources-for-toefl-preparation
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14794/provide-general-terms-for-grammatic-errors-in-sentence-and-resources-to-fix-the-s
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7057/what-are-some-good-books-online-resources-for-growing-your-vocabulary

The questions are shown in the order presented in the [search page for "resources."](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=resources)

Comment: What kind of English resources are you referring to? I think dictionaries and thesauri and etymologies and such are totally appropriate. Do you think these are subjective or are you thinking of something else?

Comment: Are you referring to questions like: [Tools for reverse etymology](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19864/are-there-resources-or-tools-for-reverse-etymology), [What are your favorite English language tools?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools). These seem to be popular and not wanted to be closed. As MrHen says, even if not, they can certainly be listed here on meta.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No, they are not on topic for EL&U. Questions like that could be posted on http://writers.stackexchange.com; they have a "resources" tag.

Comment: I actually tried this out on writers.SE (http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/does-wiktionary-supply-what-writers-need-in-an-online-dictionary) and my question was voted to close and suggested to move to EL&U. I managed to keep it there with a few re-edits and comments but they certainly weren't as welcoming to such a question as this answer led me to expect.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the question being asked and the resource involved you can ask the question here on meta. For instance: [How trustworthy is WordNet?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/946/how-trustworthy-is-wordnet)