# How to improve the pseudo-anglicism question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96510/resources-to-determine-pseudo-anglicisms was closed by a diamond moderator as "Not Constructive", without any comments given.

As far as I can tell, I described what I was asking for, why I wanted it, and some possible ideas of how such a resource might work. And I think the answers would be objective. How could the question be improved?

[This answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1098/1420) on meta suggests that at least some resources questions are on-topic, at least on meta.

I initially thought about asking it on meta, rather than main, but I decided to post it on the latter as that is where most [resources](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) questions are asked.

Comment: NB: All moderators are "diamond" moderators.

Comment: @Robusto This seems to be a popular tautology: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role

Comment: Please note that most "resources" questions get closed. As the one who closed your question, I endorse @Robusto's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this section](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#close) of the FAQ. Under "not constructive" it specifically states:

> We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

I think that is why your answer was closed.

Given that you believe this topic may be acceptable here on meta, why didn't you just ask it here?

Comment: Done. http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3579/resources-to-determine-pseudo-anglicisms