# Feature suggestion: dictionary lookup on double-click or context menu

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

Since we have recommended online reference sources, wouldn't it be nice to be able to access these directly from the site? I could see having either a right-click context menu to allow choosing which dictionary/thesaurus to use, or allowing the user to save a preferred resource that would be accessed from a new browser window/tab when they double-click a word. Does the site allow injection of a bit of JavaScript to handle such a feature?

**Edit:** This would be in addition to any similar tools already provided by the browser/addins/OS, because: 1. there are some resources that these don't take into account and 2. it would be a way to ensure (or insinuate) that "official sites" are used.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea for a [userscript](http://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts)...

Comment: Thanks, @Shog9, I will check that out.

Answer (score 6):

### First off:

Are you on a Mac?

And if so, would you be happy with the *New Oxford American Dictionary* and the *Oxford American Writer's Thesaurus*?

- ### Yes

  You're in luck—it's built into the OS.

  In your browser, select the word and right-click. From the contextual menu, choose "Look up in Dictionary"

  > [image: Look up in Dictionary]

  Once you've done that, a little tool tip menu will appear showing the definition. If you actually wanted a synonym, choose "Thesaurus" instead.
- ### No

  What might work for you are what are known as *bookmarklets*—little bits of JavaScript code that that live in your bookmarks bar. When you find one, drag it into your bookmarks bar. Then when you select a word in your browser, you can click on your new bookmark, and you should (depending on your popup blocker) see a new window appear with the word's definition.

  Here's a couple of places you can get them:

  - **Answers.com**

    They use the *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, 4th edition and *Roget's II: The New Thesaurus*, 3rd edition.

    They have a variety of add-ons on their [product page](http://www.answers.com/main/product_info.jsp). Along with bookmarklets, they've also got extensions and widgets for a variety of devices and browsers.
  - **Dictionary.com**

    Dictionary.com has a [page of bookmarklets](http://dictionary.reference.com/tools/allbookmarklets.html) (or as they refer to them, "Browser buttons"). Just look for the one that's the closest match to your browser.

    I couldn't find any definitive reference on their site as to where they get their information.

Comment: Also, if you are on a Mac you can use Spotlight to search the dictionary. I type Command-Space + the word I want.

Comment: Both of the links under "no" are dead.

Answer (score 2):

The big problem with this is that not all dictionaries are created equal. We have had [collisions between dictionaries](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/946/how-trustworthy-is-wordnet) in the past. When I look for a dictionary link I choose one that helps illustrate my point; whether that means focusing on etymology, aggregation, wikis, British, American, pronunciation.

The length of time it takes to double-click and search your bookmarked dictionary isn't really that bad. Since time seems to be the only true advantage to doing this, I suggest that it isn't worth it.

Answer (score 2):

I use such a thing every day on Firefox, an add-on called [Dictionary Tooltip](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dictionary-tooltip/). I double-click a word; a small icon pops up near the word; I click the icon, and a small/resizable pop-up window appears that automatically searches any on-line website I have set it to. The pop-up is very fast, much faster than opening a new tab.

[image]

I have it set to Babylon Info by default, because that's very fast, and it auto-detects the language of the word. In a drop-down menu, you can have DT search other websites with a click. Several dictionary websites are built in, but you can add any custom website. You could add the OED if you have an on-line subscription to its website, or any searchable website, like StackExchange, if you want to quickly look up whether there exists a question about it. You can set DT to jump to certain headers on the page. Click anywhere outside the pop-up to close it. The pop-up has a button to open it (one time) as a tab in the browser, with the search results as a regular page.

This is the [best search engine link](http://info.babylon.com/cgi-bin/bis.fcgi?rt=ol&tid=pop&mr=2&term=$$&tl=en) to add the incredibly fast Babylon Info as a custom search website, which is rather difficult to find (it has many links of varying speed and quality). The `$$` in the link is what Dictionary Tooltip uses in place of the search string (it will only work as a bookmark in your browser if you replace $$ with %s). Babylon shows part of the Wikipedia article (with clickable link) if it can't find the word in any of its languages.

[image]

---

Both this and the following look-up were done with automated language recognition by Babylon, so no selecting necessary: just double-click the word, click the icon, and voilà. You can also set the pop-up to activate without having to click the icon, but this gives you more control. The settings menus are a bit awkward; try not to let that put you off.

---

[image]

---

As you can see, there's a small text ad at the top of the pop-up that apparently isn't blocked by Adblock; I am in way affiliated with this extension.

I don't think we really need this built into SE, unless it's either optional or completely unobtrusive and fast; the site is already very heavy on the CPU of this old PC I'm using, and I wouldn't want it to bog down even more. As it is, I am forced to type comments in an external editor, because they have terrible lag here.

Answer (score 1):

This would certainly save time.
However, I believe only official sites should be used. i.e. Urban Dictionary is not official, with plenty of racial slurs, and un-censored material.

Comment: ...and poor quality. If you've never heard a word before, it's a start. If you have heard the word before, then sometimes it's spot on, other times...not.

Comment: Urban Dict is sometimes the only way for me, as a non native speaker of English, to get an idea of what something (used in real life) could mean.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this belongs in a browser plugin, not as a part of the site implemented using Javascript or something.  I've come across sites before that hijack your double click; they're extremely annoying and stop you from selecting text properly.  I end up disabling Javascript's ability to hijack double-click.  As for a right-click context menu; this would mean hijacking right-click, which again I really don't like.

When I need to look up a word in the dictionary, I type it into my Firefox search bar, select the dictionary I want, and hit enter; takes me 5 seconds.  I say we don't need this feature.